# No puedo llenar un array en ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

estoy intentando llenar un array dentro de react utilizando el hook "useState" para almacenar el contenido de este, pero al momento de iterarlo con un bucle for para rellenarlo, solo almacena el último valor del for.

Este es mi código:

```
    const [horarios,setHorarios] = useState([]);

    const llenarArregloDeHorarios = () => {
        for (let i=0; i<5;i++) {
            setHorarios([...horarios, i])
        }
    }
```

Al momento de revisar el state, veo que este solo almacena un 4, a alguien se le ocurre cuál puede ser el problema? he estado probando varias cosas, pero ninguna me funciona. Desde ya muchas gracias :(

Comment: ¿Cual es la estructura que intentas obtener en `horarios`? lo que propones  quedaría `horarios = [0,1,2,3,4]`, ¿Es así? Saludos

Comment: Si, eso es lo que espero que esté dentro del array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que has intentado no funciona ya que la actualización del estado mediante el *hook* `useState` es asíncrona, es decir, no se actualiza al instante de la llamada a la función `setState`, en tu caso `setHorarios`.

Para ello, las funciones `setState` pueden recibir una función (*callback*) que se ejecutará cuando el estado del componente haya sido actualizado, siendo sintácticamente así `setState(estadoPrevio => nuevoEstado)`. Entonces, tu código para resolver la asincronía quedaría así:

```
const [horarios,setHorarios] = useState([]);

const llenarArregloDeHorarios = () => {
  for (let i=0; i<5;i++) {
    setHorarios(horarios =>[...horarios, i])
  }
}
```

Comment: No tenía idea de que eran asíncronos, muchas gracias por tu ayuda! saludos

Comment: @NicolásCorrea, recuerda aceptar y votar por la respuesta si consideras que fue de ayuda, saludos